# Dynamically hide and show Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, interaction

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this, using `axis` in `tikzpicture`:

[image]

I'm currently ploting curves this way :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6} %Update pgfplots package version.
\usepackage{lscape,rotating,pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=22cm,height=12cm,
legend columns=1,grid=both, legend cell align={left},
ymin=-4,ymax=4,xmin=0,xmax=4,
xlabel = Lenght L (m),ylabel = Wave amplitude A (-),
]
\addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,red] {2*sin(2*pi/4*deg(x))};
\addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,blue] {2*sin(2*pi/5*deg((x))};
\addlegendentry{Wave1}
\addlegendentry{Wave2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JouleV Sadly nothing, I would like some help to start working on this (maybe a specific package or something else).

Comment: As you can see: I misunderstood your question. Please explain your question furthuer, and maybe a sketch of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JouleV : Well, as you can see on the picture, I would like to be able to hide and show predefined curves directly from the PDF produced. For example with checkboxes in the legend (like the example in the picture).

Comment: I am not sure that's possible without having a multipage pdf with all possible combinations of on and off. With a multipage pdf it is certainly possible, this is how the beamer buttons work. And sorry, your example is not particular useful. Apart from missing the preamble and `\end{document}` you are loading data that no one has (in order to plot seemingly straight lines...).

Comment: @marmot, I was thinking to do that, but 8 pages! I skipped... lol Maybe with `\foreach`...

Comment: @Sigur `\foreach` is your friend for such things. You do not have to literally draw 8 pages but only `\foreach \X in {0,1}{\foreach \Y in {0,1}{\foreach \Z in {0,1}{.... stuff with \ifnum ...}}}`.

Comment: This is possible with the ocgx2 package. https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2 Your code is not compileable, which complicates a response.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your help. Well I just need help to know where to start if I want to acheieve this. The example I gave is for people to know what I currently use to plot non-dynamic curves. I will implement it myself if needed :)

Comment: @marmot, exactly what I am doing, but with `\i,\j,\k`... :-)

Comment: @marmot, the tikzpicture should be inside loop to produce multiple page document, right?

Comment: @Sigur I think so. (I have no idea if ocgx2 can help here, I never used it explicitly. It could. Then the answer may be different and simpler.)

Comment: @marmot, oh, just now I saw that OP didn't provide the csv data.

Comment: @joseldsm, could you please provide the csv file to us?

Comment: Example upgraded :)

Comment: @joseldsm, I'll try to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be compiled twice. **Use** Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, *(evince ?)* or PDF readers that manage *OCG layers*.

I simply adapted the code of the example given in the `ocgx` and `ocgx2` package. 
I'll leave it to you to do the finishing touches.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=4cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadows,chains,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6} %Update pgfplots package version.
\usepackage{calculator,float}
\usepackage{lscape,rotating,pdflscape}

\tikzset{%
  button on/.style={%
    draw,minimum size=5mm,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=blue!50,rounded corners,
    switch ocg with mark on={#1}{},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=22cm,height=12cm,
legend columns=1,grid=both, legend cell align={left},
ymin=-4,ymax=4,xmin=0,xmax=4,
xlabel = Lenght L (m),ylabel = Wave amplitude A (-),
]
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Wawe1 example,ref=Wawe1,status=invisible}]
\addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,red] {2*sin(2*pi/4*deg(x))};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Wawe2 example,ref=Wawe2,status=invisible}]
\addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,blue] {2*sin(2*pi/5*deg((x))};
\end{scope}

\addlegendentry{Wave1}
\addlegendentry{Wave2}
\end{axis}
    \node[button on=Wawe1]at (-2,10)(but){};
    \node[right=0 of but]{Wawe1};
    \node[below=3pt of but,button on=Wawe2](but){};
    \node[right=0 of but]{Wawe2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

If you do not want the functions to be visible from the beginning, you must use the key `switch ocg with mark off` and not `switch ocg with mark on`

That's what gives:

```
\tikzset{%
  button on/.style={%
    draw,minimum size=5mm,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=blue!50,rounded corners,
    switch ocg with mark off={#1}{},
  },
}
```

Comment: Very nice! `\pagestyle{empty}` would be good.

Comment: With evince in Linux Mint, in full screen mode, the button does not work, since when clicked on it, it goes to next page, that is, end of file. Maybe a problem with my evince.

Comment: I don't have evince and therefore I can't test. This compatibility is the one given by Paul Gaborit in his demo of the `ocgx` package here: http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf \pagestyle{empty} would be good but it's his MWE

Answer (score 3):

For 2 functions we have `2^2=4` possibilities. for more functions, the code would be much complicated.

In full screen mode, click on the check mark to navigate to pdf page and see the functions.

[image]

[image]

**M(W)E**

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\colorOn}{green!80!black}
\newcommand{\colorOff}{black!30}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,1}{
\foreach \j in {0,1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  width=22cm,height=12cm,
  legend columns=1,grid=both, legend cell align={left},
  ymin=-4,ymax=4,xmin=0,xmax=4,
  xlabel = Lenght $L$ (m), ylabel = Wave amplitude $A$ (-),
  ]
  \ifnum \i=1 
    \addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,red] {2*sin(2*pi/4*deg(x))}; 
    \addlegendentry{Wave1}
  \fi
  \ifnum \j=1 
    \addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200,blue] {2*sin(2*pi/5*deg((x))}; 
    \addlegendentry{Wave2}
  \fi
  \end{axis}
  \node[anchor=east,minimum width=4cm] (f) at (-2,6) {%
    $f(x)=2\sin(\frac{2\pi}{4}\deg(x))$
    \ifnum \i=0
      \ifnum \j=0
        \hypertarget{fOffgOff}{}%
        \hyperlink{fOngOff}{\textcolor{\colorOff}{\checkmark}} 
      \else
        \hypertarget{fOffgOn}{}%
        \hyperlink{fOngOn} {\textcolor{\colorOff}{\checkmark}} 
      \fi 
    \else 
      \ifnum \j=0
        \hypertarget{fOngOff}{}%
        \hyperlink{fOffgOff}{\textcolor{\colorOn}{\checkmark}} 
      \else
        \hypertarget{fOngOn}{}%
        \hyperlink{fOffgOn} {\textcolor{\colorOn}{\checkmark}} 
      \fi 
    \fi
  };
  \node[below of=f] (g)  {%
    $g(x)=2\sin(\frac{2\pi}{5}\deg(x))$ 
    \ifnum \i=0
      \ifnum \j=0
        \hyperlink{fOffgOn}{\textcolor{\colorOff}{\checkmark}} 
      \else
        \hyperlink{fOffgOff} {\textcolor{\colorOn}{\checkmark}} 
      \fi 
    \else 
      \ifnum \j=0
        \hyperlink{fOngOn}{\textcolor{\colorOff}{\checkmark}} 
      \else
        \hyperlink{fOngOff} {\textcolor{\colorOn}{\checkmark}} 
      \fi 
    \fi
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{document}
```